# Write pandas data frame to set

Tags: python, pandas, set

I have a pd dataframe as follows:

```
value | x | y | hash
10    | 1 | 2 | abcdef
15    | 3 | 1 | flkjd
```

I would like to convert the hash column to an "empty" dictionary (I believe it is called a set):

```
{"abcdef" : NULL, "flkjd" : NULL} #etc
```

So that I can eventually populate the dictionary with custom objects. Is there a quick way I can do this without iterating over the dataframe (as I've been advised not to)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `{k:None for k in df['hash']}` or just `set(df['hash'])`?

Comment: That worked, thanks !!

`set(df['hash'])`

Comment: Sets and empty dicts are completely different things.

Comment: Thank you! I read somewhere that "empty" dicts were functionally the same as sets. My apologies (edited title)